# Java Scanner and line continuation

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to read records from a file. A single record can be spanned over multiple lines. These lines are connected by an '-' (minus).
Sample File:

```
Alice, 23, SampleRoad 120, SampleTown
Bob, 25, SampleRoad 15A, SampleTown, -
     Tel: 0545848, Mail: bob@hotmail.com
Chris, 27, SampleRoad, SampleTown
```

I use the Scanner class for reading the file:

```
private static void readFile(String fileName) {

    Pattern PATTERN_RECORD = Pattern.compile(".*", Pattern.MULTILINE);

    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.useDelimiter("(?!-)[\\r\\n]+"); //not a '-' followed by crlf

        int iRecord = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext(PATTERN_RECORD)) {
            System.out.println(++iRecord + ": " + scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the scanners delimiter pattern defines what is handled as a "record".

This is the result:

```
1: Alice, 23, SampleRoad 120, SampleTown
2: Bob, 25, SampleRoad 15A, SampleTown, -
3:          Tel: 0545848, Mail: bob@hotmail.com
4: Chris, 27, SampleRoad, SampleTown
```

This is what I want:

```
1: Alice, 23, SampleRoad 120, SampleTown
2: Bob, 25, SampleRoad 15A, SampleTown, Tel: 0545848, Mail: bob@hotmail.com
3: Chris, 27, SampleRoad, SampleTown
```

Maybe the Scanner class is not suitable here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your delimiter regex.  You should use a lookbehind instead of a lookahead.  Try changing it like this:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("(?<!-)[\\r\\n]+");
```

Comment: thanks, but now only the first record is selected. Any ideas how to skip unmatched records without explicitly define an skip pattern?

Comment: That would be because of you `PATTERN_RECORD`, did you intend to use the `DOTALL` flag instead of the `MULTILINE`?  If you change that, it would work, but you don't even require it, you could also you `hasNext()`.

Comment: `scanner.useDelimiter("(?<!-)[\\r\\n]+");` and `scanner.hasNext()` doesn't match the multiline records. Also the `DOTALL` flag doesn't change anything

Comment: Strange, after your previous comment I took your code and tested with exactly those changes and it's working fine.  What do you get as output?

Comment: Hmm, don't know how to insert a new line in the comments: Here's the ouput: 1: Alice, 23, SampleRoad 120, SampleTown<br/>
2: Bob, 25, SampleRoad 15A, SampleTown, -<br/>
<br/>
3:          Tel: 0545848, Mail: bob@hotmail.com<br/>
4: Chris, 27, SampleRoad, SampleTown<br/>

Comment: Are you running on a windows system?

Comment: Then try changing it to this: `"(?<!-)\r\n"`

Answer (score 2):

Plain readers could be faster in your case.

```
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/data"));
    String prev = null;
    String current = null;
    while ((current = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (prev == null) {
            prev = current;
            continue;
        }
        final boolean shouldJoin = prev.endsWith("-");
        if (!shouldJoin) {
            System.out.println(prev);
            prev = current;
            continue;
        }
        prev = prev.substring(0, prev.length() - 1) + current.substring(5);
    }
    if (prev != null) {
        System.out.println(prev);
    }
    in.close();
```